# I can't get my image to be updated with the new one in node js express file uploader, I couldn't figure it out

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, file-upload

I'm trying to update my post and everything is working except the image, when I update the image src is becoming UNKNOWN, this is my code:

```
exports.updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });
    let uploadeImage = req.files.image;
    let uploadPath = __dirname + "/../public/uploads/" + uploadeImage.name;
    uploadeImage.mv(uploadPath, async () => {
      post.image = "/uploads/" + uploadeImage.name;
      post.title = req.body.title;
      post.desc = req.body.desc;
      post.image = req.body.uploadeImage;
      post.save();
      res.status(200).redirect("/posts");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show us what uploadImage looks like? `console.log(uploadImage)`

Comment: {
  name: 'brad-pouncey-lpMLTW7orQA-unsplash.jpg',
  data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e2 02 1c 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 02 0c 6c 63 6d 73 02 10 00 00 ... 646445 more bytes>,
  size: 646495,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  md5: 'e0c36559aeba5215e6e5d484e3bec92d',
  mv: [Function: mv]
}

Comment: I'm getting the image but can't passed it to the post i believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) as a middleware in front of your route to upload files
then in your route you have access to **req.file** ,store reference in db as:

```
post.image= req.file.filename // or full path
```